# Testlink Installation defaulting to "Upgrade" when "New Installation" is the only option available

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, centos-7

I have been working on setting up testlink on a fresh centos 7 VM that I deployed this morning. It's obviously a brand new server and has never had the software installed previously.

But when I go through the web portal to install, the installation is defaulting to an upgrade and is not creating my database on the second final installation screen.

I am using the following setup:

- nginx 1.14.2
- mysql 5.7
- php 7.2

Here are screenshots of my current install process:

Select New install:

[Test link Install Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGcvp.png)

Agree to Terms:

[terms and conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcO16.png)

Verify System Requirements:

[Sysetm Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1fF5.png)

Setup DB users and access (at this point it says I have requested an upgrade, and as you can see from image 1 that only a fresh install is available to choose from and I have no original install to update:

[Database Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzISQ.png)

Confirmation DB connection worked and it was able to access the testlink DB, but it says I am trying to upgrade from version 1.7 and that I should select upgrade but there is no option available to do so.

[Setup fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIiSy.png)

Has anyone run into this issue? Do we have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I never imagined that superuser would be so helpful. Pretty awesome that we are recommended to ask for help on a subset of stackoverflow that no one actually checks or uses...

Anyways, I rebuilt my box and went down a version of the software and was able to fix the problem. There is an issue with the newest version of mysql and the syntax of the softwares queries.

To get around this I modified the php code in installUtils.php

```
// 20070310 - $the_host -> $db_host        
if (strlen(trim($db_host)) != 0)
{
  $stmt .= "@" . "'" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($db_host) . "'";
}         
$stmt .= " IDENTIFIED BY '" .  $passwd . "'"; // this is bad
```

Should be:

```
   // 20070310 - $the_host -> $db_host        
if (strlen(trim($db_host)) != 0)
{
  $stmt .= "@" . "'" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($db_host) . "'";
}         
// $stmt .= " IDENTIFIED BY '" .  $passwd . "'"; // this is good
```

And:

```
if( strcasecmp('localhost',$db_host) != 0)
  {
    // 20060514 - franciscom - missing 
    $stmt = "GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON " . 
             "`" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($db_name) . "`" . ".* TO " . 
             "'" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($login) . "'@'localhost'" .
            " IDENTIFIED BY '" .  $passwd . "'"; // this is bad
    if ( !@$dbhandler->exec_query($stmt) ) 
    {
      $op->msg = "ko - " . $dbhandler->error_msg();
      $op->status_ok=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Should be:

```
if( strcasecmp('localhost',$db_host) != 0)
  {
    // 20060514 - franciscom - missing 
    $stmt = "GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON " . 
             "`" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($db_name) . "`" . ".* TO " . 
             "'" . $dbhandler->prepare_string($login) . "'@'localhost'"; // this is good
    if ( !@$dbhandler->exec_query($stmt) ) 
    {
      $op->msg = "ko - " . $dbhandler->error_msg();
      $op->status_ok=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Once again, thank you for the support, not sure what I would do with out you.